# Use grep, sed, or awk to extract lines from files?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep, sed

I want migrate from openLDAP Authentication to another Authentication methods. My main problem is the sudoers, where I need to manually migrate them.

Thus, I need to create a script for that. I would like to use bash for this. 
The ldif file contains lines like the following:

```
dn: cn=Devs, ou=SUDOers, dc=example,dc=com
sudoUser: %devs
sudoCommand: /bin/su - command
sudoCommand: /bin/su - wwwadmin
sudoHost: ALL
description: Developer Admin
objectClass: sudoRole
cn: Devs
```

So, what I need to do is:

1. Read the LDIF file.
2. Extract all lines between dn: and a blank line, OR, between the lines containing cn: Devs

I would like to use embedded BASH commands, grep, awk, sed etc only.

**No Python, PHP, Perl etc.**

Comment: Why don't you take the output of only the desired attributes directly to your ldiff file?

Comment: Because, I would need to go and perform 100s of LDAP queries.

Comment: No Perl? No Python? No additional LDAP queries? What's with deliberately choosing the hard way?...

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: David, I really don't see the point of your comment.
I am not asking someone to write the script of me, thank you. I am asking how to use specific commands. 
Anyway, I found what I can do and I will answer my own question.

Comment: @grawity: Since I don't have the list of sudoers, I need to either get the cn from LDAP and then for each cn do an ldap query to get the attributes, or to export everything in a file and parse the file. The non pythong,PHP, perl etc is not my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found an easy way using sed:

```
sed -n '/start_search/,/end_search/p' filename)
```

- start_search is the pattern of the first line
- end_search is the pattern of the last line.

In my case, start_search is 'dn: cn='
and the end_search is '^cn:' or '^$'